# How to avoid overlapping of the x-labels of a Seaborn swarm plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, graph, seaborn

I'm trying to create a swarm plot with 2 datas, but as one of them is very extensive, its labels keep overlapping. I am completely lost.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.set_context("poster")  
sns.swarmplot(x = "GDP_Billions_PPP", y="Score2019", data=df )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A swarmplot is well suited for plotting a bunch of categories, not more than maybe 20 or so. Else you would probably like to convert the strings to numbers and plot a scatter instead.

Comment: Just a note for your question: I think you mean 'seaborn' not 'seabord'